# How to handle long words In email newsletter design for yahoo and AOL mail

Tags: html, html-table, html-email, inline-styles, html4

Actually I'm creating newsletter design which is two columns, and it has images, title and text on each column respectively. Currently, facing layout styling issues where I can't able to handle long German word which is "Donaudampfschiffahrtselektrizitätenhauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft" for title content

Currently, this is the html4 table structure i'm using

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="margin:0 auto;padding:32px 0 0 0;background-color:#f8f6f1;word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-all">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td style="padding:20px">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" style="margin:0 auto">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:#ffffff">
           
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td width="50%" valign="middle" style="width:50%;padding:20px 10px 10px 20px;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle">
     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" width="100%" height="auto" style="display:block;height:auto;width:100%" alt="">    </td>
    <td width="50%" valign="middle" style="width:50%;padding:20px 20px 10px 10px;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:middle">
     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" width="100%" height="auto" style="display:block;height:auto;width:100%" alt="">    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="50%" valign="middle" style="width:50%;padding:10px 10px 5px 20px;overflow:hidden;word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-all;vertical-align:middle">
            <h2 style="margin:0;padding:0">
        Donaudampfschiffahrtselektrizitätenhauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft</h2>
         </td>
    <td width="50%" valign="middle" style="width:50%;padding:10px 20px 5px 10px;overflow:hidden;word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-all;vertical-align:middle">
            <h2 style="margin:0;padding:0">
        Donaudampfschiffahrtselektrizitätenhauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft</h2>
         </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="50%" valign="middle" style="width:50%;padding:0 10px 20px 20px;overflow:hidden;word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-all;vertical-align:middle">
     <p>Et epicurei phaedrum mnesarchum has, quem primis ancillae est ad, cetero tractatos mei in? Pri te laoreet postulant, te fugit accusata eam!</p>

<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate.</p>
     
               <a style="display:inline-block;color:#f6c3aa;text-decoration:none" href="https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=margin" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s%3Dmargin&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1709898494141000&amp;usg=AOvVaw0ibbIDF5zZyxhZPKgn8I9T">
            <span style="color:#f6c3aa;text-decoration:none">rindfleischetikettierungsü<wbr>berwachungsaufgabenübertragung<wbr>sgesetz</span>
          </a>
                              </td>
    <td width="50%" valign="middle" style="width:50%;padding:0 20px 20px 10px;overflow:hidden;word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-all;vertical-align:middle">
     <p>Et epicurei phaedrum mnesarchum has, quem primis ancillae est ad, cetero tractatos mei in? Pri te laoreet postulant, te fugit accusata eam!</p>

<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate.</p>
 
               <a style="display:inline-block;color:#f6c3aa;text-decoration:none" href="https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=margin" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s%3Dmargin&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1709898494141000&amp;usg=AOvVaw0ibbIDF5zZyxhZPKgn8I9T">
            <span style="color:#f6c3aa;text-decoration:none">rindfleischetikettierungsü<wbr>berwachungsaufgabenübertragung<wbr>sgesetz</span>
          </a>
                              </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>


        <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" style="text-align:center;padding:16px">
            <small style="font-size:10px;color:#4a4847">
              Powered by <a href="#" style="color:#4a4847" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="#">TYRIO</a>
            </small>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

How to handle these type of scenarios while coming to email newsletter design. Reference screenshot provided below for yahoo and AOL mail.

Screenshot

[image: AOL mail screenshot]

[image: yahoo email screenshot]

Comment: Mobile has good support for `word-break: break-all` so you can use that in mobile devices and as for desktop, maybe you can reduce the font size a little and increase the width of the email (just a thought)

Answer (score 1):

There are two main methods. Apply a wrapping style, or add something to the text itself.

I don't believe there are any valid wrapping styles that can used here as Yahoo/AOL doesn't support it, as you've found e.g. a style "`word-break: break-all`" is not supported (https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-word-break/). "Overflow" should work though - but is less than ideal.

Best bet is to add `<wbr>` several times in the middle of the text. This is an *optional* br (break), and will be used to wrap the text at that point if the email client needs it.

ie:

`Donaudampf<wbr>schiffahrt<wbr>selektrizitäten<wbr>haupt<wbr>betriebswerk<wbr>bauunterbeamten<wbr>gesellschaft`